# Multiplying an integer with a currency in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, visual-studio-macros, vba

In my excel table i have one row (5th row) as number of items and another (6th row) as the price of the items. For example i want to multiply 200 with $56.50 but I am having a problem with this script. Can anyone please help.

```
Sub calcprice()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim iRowNumber As Integer   ' Integer to store result in
    Dim val As Double

    iRowNumber = InputBox(Prompt:="Number of Rows", _
          Title:="Rows: ", Default:="# of Rows")
    For i = 1 To iRowNumber
        If Cells(i, 5).Value >= 0 And Cells(i, 6).Value >= 0 And IsEmpty(Cells(i, 5)) = False And IsEmpty(Cells(i, 5)) = False Then
            val = FormatCurrency(Cells(i, 5).Value) * Cells(i, 6).Value
            Cells(i, 7).Value = val
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

it says runtime error 13
type mismatch
here is the image:
[image: it says currency]

Here is the link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lla2cuz8hqu5qyp/test.xlsm

also i cannot use the =a*b i have to use macros!

Comment: Why are you using FormatCurrency to convert a value to a string, and then multiplying the string by a number?

Comment: how would i convert both of the cells(i,5).value and cells(i, 6).value both to doubles so that i can mutiply them.

Comment: All numbers (numbers, dates, times, currency etc) in Excel are held as doubles regardless of how they are formatted. You don't need to do any conversion, particularly if you use .Value 2 rather than .Value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a loop

You can work with a single shot range in colunm G that

- Adds a formula from G5 to the user entered `iRowNumber` to test whether a result > 0 happens in each row (or adds `""` for a 0 result)
- overwrite the formulae with the values

  ```
  Sub calcprice()
      Dim iRowNumber As Long   ' Integer to store result in        
  iRowNumber = InputBox(Prompt:="Number of Rows", _
        Title:="Rows: ", Default:="# of Rows")

  With Range(Cells(5, 7), Cells(iRowNumber, 7))
  .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(N(RC[-1]*RC[-2]),RC[-1]*RC[-2],"""")"
  .Value = .Value
  End With
  End Sub
  ```

Comment: +1 don't use loops unless you need them, i.e. not a tenth as often as you think you do.

Comment: How would i do it with a loop. I dont understand 'with' statments yet so can you show me how to do it in a for loop?

Comment: Rather than `With` I could have used these two longer statements,  `Range(Cells(5, 7), Cells(iRowNumber, 7)).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(N(RC[-1]*RC[-2]),RC[-1]*RC[-2],"""")"` `Range(Cells(5, 7), Cells(iRowNumber, 7)).Value = .Value`. I advise you not to go the loop way - its inefficient. I can talk you through these two lines in more detail if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. Remember to format the 5th cell and the 6th cell to the currency you like!

```
    Sub calcprice()

    Dim iRowNumber As Integer
    Dim val As Double


    iRowNumber = InputBox(Prompt:="Number of Rows", _
          Title:="Rows: ", Default:="# of Rows")


    For i = 1 To iRowNumber
        If Cells(i, 5).Value >= 0 And Cells(i, 6) >= 0 Then
            If Cells(i, 6).Value > 0 Then
                val = Cells(i, 5).Value * FormatCurrency(Cells(i, 6).Value)
                Cells(i, 7).Value = val
            End If

        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think there is need for the `Dim i As Integer`, it is declared in the for-loop.

Comment: However, it does not work when there is no value in the 5th row.

Comment: Ah, wait, I thought it was vise versa. Then it is just to change the place of FormatCurrency.

Comment: Could you please try the newer version of the code, this ought to work!

Comment: Could you please include a copy that file in the post? (parts of it)

Answer (score 0):

You have `For i = 1 to iRowNumber`

The image shows that the data starts in row 5. The previous rows contain text.

Therefore, try `For i = 5 to iRowNumber`